# JSON into HTML for phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am trying to create a phonegap app for my website... however I need to add recieve the data from the website and show it on my app...

I have modified the website to show information in the json format as shown here http://belladoni.co.nz/index.php?route=product/category&path=59&json

How do I show this information from the json in the app? how do I echo it? How do i get it to show the images mentioned in the json?

Please help and please provide a working [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) if possible

my json looks like the following:

```
"items": [{"product_id":"85","thumb":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/image\/cache\/data\/Old Mill Road\/Flower Globe Green-164x264.jpg","name":"Antique Flower Globe","description":"Have beautifully arranged flower posies in your home all the time with this goregous glass flower gl..","price":"$22.89","special":false,"tax":"$19.90","rating":0,"reviews":"Based on 0 reviews.","href":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/decor\/Antique-Flower-Globe"},{"product_id":"54","thumb":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/image\/cache\/data\/Maytime\/FB Double Closed 1-164x264.jpeg","name":"Birds of Flight, Set of 3","description":"Beautifully graceful and delicate, these birds are fabulous and create an instant work of art w..","price":"$95.00","special":false,"tax":"$82.61","rating":0,"reviews":"Based on 0 reviews.","href":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/decor\/Flying-Bird-#1"},{"product_id":"56","thumb":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/image\/cache\/data\/Oneworld\/CHANDELIER COASTERS SET4 ES8021-164x264.jpg","name":"Chandelier Coasters Set of 4","description":"Beautiful set of 4 coasters featuring chandeliers, birds, butterflys and roses ... shabby chic at it..","price":"$29.90","special":false,"tax":"$26.00","rating":0,"reviews":"Based on 0 reviews.","href":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/decor\/Chandelier-Coasters-Set-of-4"},{"product_id":"62","thumb":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/image\/cache\/data\/Maytime\/Cushion; Circle Cotton Cinnamon-164x264.jpeg","name":"Cinnamon Circle Cushion","description":"Vibrant cotton circle cushion in a yummy cinnamon colour.\r\n\r\nPair with our Dandelion Cushion for a g..","price":"$59.90","special":false,"tax":"$52.09","rating":0,"reviews":"Based on 0 reviews.","href":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/decor\/Cinnamon-Circle-Cushion"},{"product_id":"86","thumb":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/image\/cache\/data\/Old Mill Road\/Angel-164x264.jpg","name":"Gorgeous Waiting Angel","description":"Oh so cute! \nA percentage of the proceeds generated from sales of our Waiting Angels will be do..","price":"$19.90","special":false,"tax":"$17.30","rating":0,"reviews":"Based on 0 reviews.","href":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/decor\/Gorgeous-Waiting-Angel"},{"product_id":"102","thumb":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/image\/cache\/data\/Seaco\/VintageCrownCandle003-164x264.png","name":"Vintage Crown Candle","description":"Gorgeous vintage candle bearing a royal crown.  These majestic candles command attention and th..","price":"$19.90","special":false,"tax":"$19.90","rating":0,"reviews":"Based on 0 reviews.","href":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/decor\/Vintage-Crown-Candle"},{"product_id":"103","thumb":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/image\/cache\/data\/Seaco\/VintageCrownCandle002-164x264.png","name":"Vintage Crown Candle","description":"Gorgeous vintage candle bearing a royal crown.  These majestic candles command attention and th..","price":"$19.90","special":false,"tax":"$19.90","rating":0,"reviews":"Based on 0 reviews.","href":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/decor\/Vintage-Crown-Candle-1081"},{"product_id":"59","thumb":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/image\/cache\/data\/Seaco\/VintageCrownCandle001-164x264.png","name":"Vintage Crown Candle","description":"Gorgeous vintage candle bearing a royal crown.  These majestic candles command attention and th..","price":"$19.90","special":false,"tax":"$19.90","rating":0,"reviews":"Based on 0 reviews.","href":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/decor\/Vintage-Crown-Candle-Set-of-Four"},{"product_id":"57","thumb":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/image\/cache\/data\/Seaco\/VintageParisCrownCushion-164x264.jpg","name":"Vintage Paris Cushion","description":"A beautiful Provincial cushion that will give a french touch to any decor.  Linen filled c..","price":"$52.17","special":false,"tax":"$52.17","rating":0,"reviews":"Based on 0 reviews.","href":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/decor\/Vintage-Paris-Cushion"},{"product_id":"58","thumb":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/image\/cache\/data\/Seaco\/VintageParisCrownCushion70x35-164x264.jpg","name":"Vintage Paris Cushion Long","description":"A beautiful Provincial cushion that will give a french touch to any decor.  \n\nLinen filled..","price":"$50.00","special":false,"tax":"$43.48","rating":0,"reviews":"Based on 0 reviews.","href":"http:\/\/belladoni.co.nz\/decor\/Vintage-Paris-Cushion-Long"}]
```

Comment: Try using a templating library like one of these: http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

Comment: Using JS, You can iterate through the json like any other object, build a string containing your HTML output, and insert it into the dom.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to javascript and json etc and I don't know how to insert into dom etc... (sorry I am a nob)

Answer (score 1):

See my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3SakE/4/

Your JSON looks broken so it will not work correctly, but you should be able to get the idea.

```
$.getJSON('http://belladoni.co.nz/index.php?route=product/category&path=59&json', function(data){

    $.each(data['items'], function(key, val){
        $('#results').append("<p>"+key+"</br>"+val+"</p>"); 
    });

    //or iterate through each item in the object like so
    $('#results').text(data.items.price);

});
```

Comment: It is running opencart so I added in the following line `echo json_encode($this->data['products']);` How ever I i did think it wans't formatting properly so I added a `items:` in fron of it... please try it now and see if you can get it working

Comment: What do I need to do to fix the json... I know nothing about how it is meant to be formatted and I have just tried using it exactly as PHP generates it and I still get the same result

Comment: I have managed to get this working on here http://jsfiddle.net/zJjrh/5/ so i have tried to do it externally which i have managed to do with this code... however I cannot get it to load it from an external json file, which would be http://belladoni.co.nz/index.php?route=product/category&path=59&json instead...... please help

Comment: It may be because of Acess-Control-Allow-Origin check in the console to see if any errors are coming up... You may need to add "header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');" to the top of index.php (without the quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Mustache.js ( Templating Library).

Or You have to manually Iterate thought the each JSON object and construct the HTML and Append to your website body.

My suggestion is go through the Mustache.js.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how do I use Mustache.js? do you have any examples... I have coded PHP for a while but have never coded anything with JavaScript...

Comment: I can get it to work on http://mustache.github.io/#demo however I cannot get it to work on http://jsfiddle.net/VCx2z/ or in real life... please help

Comment: use Mustache.to_html("html_id to append",item_json_data);

Comment: I have managed to get this working on here http://jsfiddle.net/zJjrh/6/ however I cannot get it to load it from an external json file, which would be http://belladoni.co.nz/index.php?route=product/category&path=59&json instead...... I need it to load an external json, please help and advise what changes I need